# Is it possible to force IDA to acknowledge unusual frame pointer deltas?

Tags: ida

I keep coming across a compiling pattern that IDA doesn't automatically handle well.  Consider the following example:

```
mov rax, rsp       ; Set rax at the start of the function
...
lea rbp, [rax-5Fh] ; Shortly afterward, set rbp as the frame pointer at a nonstandard offset
...
mov [rbp+3Fh], rcx ; Reference all stack offsets from rbp for the rest of the function
...
```

In this example, it appears that IDA has lost track of `rbp`'s state as an offset into the stack frame, presumably because of the additional indirection.  (We copy from `rsp` to `rax` to `rbp`, rather than just from `rsp` to `rbp`)

I would like the above example to look something more like this:

```
var_20= qword ptr -20h
...
mov [rbp+5Fh+var_20], rcx
```

However, as one would expect, if I change the type of `3Fh` to be a stack offset, I get the following:

```
arg_37= qword ptr 3Fh
...
mov [rbp+arg_37], rcx
```

Which is obviously not correct.  I have two questions:

- **Is it possible to generate the desired output?**
- **If not, how would one normally deal with this?**

Solutions I am aware of:

- I could create a structure for the stack frame and specify the offset delta (occasionally also adjusting for [negative offsets](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=63)).  The downsides are that I would have to create a structure for each stack frame I analyze, and I would also not have cross-references.
- I could just use the incorrect offsets in the stack frame.  This would give me cross-references, but I would expect things to break when touching `r`, the offset storing the return address.

Also relevant: I'm using IDA Pro 6.2.

Comment: any chance you can share/link to the binary sample, would like to check this out myself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Alt+P` will bring up the `Edit function` screen.

Make sure `BP based frame` is checked, and enter your value `0x5F` into the box marked `Frame pointer delta`.

Comment: That did it, thank you!  Positive `0x5F` is the correct delta.